# Rendering flickers for a short time after launch. Workaround?

Tags: jquery, cordova, codiqa

A [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org)-based app - containing only a few relatively simple / local pages - **flickers somehow during launch**, just after the splash screen disappears and the first jQuery-based `data-role="page"` page appears.

The flicker appears in the **bar at the top of the screen**.

For roughly a **2/10 of a second, the screen appears as if CSS not yet applied**. After that, the page appears as it should, as if CSS suddenly gets applied.

**Does a standard workaround exists?** E.g. mark all `data-role="page"` pages as `display:none` and some tenth of a second later within

```
app.initialize();
```

make the pages visible.

Or may I somehow instruct [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org) to do that for me?

Seen on iPad 2.

Comment: I have gotten around this by using the splashscreen plugin. I set the splash screen to show for 30 seconds by default, and then in my code after the first page render is called I call the splashscreen plugin `hide()` method.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Thx! Good hint. So the splash screen overlays the rendered page?

Comment: Yes, this is also useful if you need to load your own data when the app loads and want the splash screen to wait until that is done. Otherwise the default is the hide as soon as the application is ready to present the webview, which can cause short flicker.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Why not write an answer instead of a comment? I'm happy to accept yours.

Comment: Because PhoneGap issues can be very random sometimes what worked for me doesn't work for others. I like to wait and see if it worked and then if it does I add an answer. Did this solve your issue?